# querying current DB table in mySQL, building a list of objects and displaying them on the page, with Java

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

Currently I am building a car rental application and I'm stuck on making this array list capable of storing all of the objects attributes and pushing it to the array. I have a java bean `package com.rental.models;

```
public class Car {

    private String Id;
    private String Year;
    private String Make;
    private String Model;
    private String Color;
    private String Available;

    public Car() {
        super();
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        Year = year;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return Make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        Make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return Model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        Model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return Color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        Color = color;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getAvailable() {
        return Available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(String available) {
        Available = available;
    }

}
```

and a List of bean results,`package com.rental.models;

```
import java.util.List;

public class CarData {

    private List<Car> cars;

    public CarData() {
        super();
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }


}
```

Lastly this is the code I am stuck on.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Car> cars;

    ResultSet rs =null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st= null;

    try {
    Context    ctx = new InitialContext();
    Context env = ( Context )ctx.lookup( "java:comp/env" );
    DataSource ds = ( DataSource )env.lookup( "jdbc/carRentalSystem");
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    st= conn.createStatement();

    rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM carrdetails" );
            if(rs.next()) {


                Car car = new Car();
                car.setId("id");
                car.setYear("Year");
                car.setMake("Make");
                car.setModel("model");
                car.setColor("Color");
                car.setAvailable("Availability");
                cars.add(car);
                return cars;
            }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
            finally {
                try{ if(st != null ) st.close(); } catch(java.sql.SQLException e){}
                try{ if(conn != null ) conn.close(); } catch(java.sql.SQLException e){}
                try{ if(rs != null) rs.close(); } catch(java.sql.SQLException e){}
            }
```

Comment: The `void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)` method can't return anything, what is your expected behavior exactly ?

Comment: I want to display the results of a list of cars, it's a car rental system, where admins can insert carts into the database and the cars can be seen by both the user and the admin, on the web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the mistake of pushing this instance into the JSP I am using. however it is working.